# How do you change your Minecraft player name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want to change mine but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 11):

Users who have a Mojang account (you sign in with your email) can change their username for free at account.mojang.com/me by clicking the (Change) link next to your profile name.

A user who changes their username cannot change it again for 30 days.

Source: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638-minecraft-usernames

Answer (score -5):

I think u can!  I've tried many websites that do work but, Try doing this one:https://minecraft.net/
    Log in and then do account settings

Comment: WRONG, WRONG, WRONG!